# Парсинг Яндекс Wordstat

Tags: php, парсер

Все добра. Пытаюсь парсить Яндекс Вордстат. После попытки авторизации выдает форму, где просит ввести привязанный к аккаунту номер телефона. Каким образом обойти эту форму, авторизоваться и взять статистику? Может для этих целей можно использовать API?

Ф-ия авторизации

```
function auth($url,$login,$passwd,$cookie_box,$idkey,$retpath,$timestamp,$twoweeks,$In) 
{
    $common_yandex = curl_init('https://passport.yandex.ru/passport?mode=auth');
    curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"login=$login&passwd=$passwd");
    curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_box);
    curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $html = curl_exec($common_yandex);
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Парсить wordstat - так себе идея. Сейчас он просит номер телефона, затем, будет постоянно кидать капчу. Очень муторное занятие.

Используйте API Директа, вижу что там можно получить отчет о статистики по ключам -  https://yandex.ru/dev/direct/doc/dg-v4/reference/CreateNewWordstatReport.html